# ciclo infinito después de empaquetar con cx_frezee

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Estoy realizando un programa que funciona sin ningún problema cuando no esta empaquetado con cx_freeze.

El problema surge cuando lo combierto a .exe ya que al tratar de cerrarlo no se cierra y habre ventana tras ventana.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver al tratar de cerrarla se abren mas..

dejo aqui el codigo del setup, el de la ventana login, y el de la ventana inicio que creo es donde se encuentra el problema

**Setup.py**

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import Executable,setup


build_op = {
    "packages":['os','firebase_01','firebase_admin','idna','requests'],
    'include_files':[
        'Busqueda.py',
        'Firebase_load.py',
        'Inicio.py',
        'Inventario.py',
        'Login.py',
        'Registro.py',
        'Sqlite.py',
        'Traspasos.py',
        'C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/N_Proyect/Db',
        'C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/N_Proyect/fire',
        'C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/N_Proyect/Images',
        'C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/N_Proyect/Interfaces',
    ]
}

setup(
    name = "Exe_PointSale",
    version = "1.0.0",
    description = "Punto de Venta",
    executables = [Executable("Login.py",base="Win32GUI")],
    options = {"build_exe":build_op}
)
```

**Login.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, Qt
from Inicio import Inicio
from Firebase_load import *

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Interfaces/Login.ui",self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground,True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground,False)

        self.closed.clicked.connect(lambda:self.close())
        self.mostrar_hora()

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.mostrar_hora)
        self.timer.start()

    def mostrar_hora(self):
        self.hora.setText(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss AP"))



class Dato(Principal):
    def __init__(self):
        Principal.__init__(self)
        self.b_login.clicked.connect(self.validate_User)

    def validate_User(self):
        user = self.l_usuario.text()

        if user == '':
            self.l_status.setText('No se ingreso un usuario')
        else:
            ref = db.reference("/usuarios")
            res = ref.get()

            for key in res.items():
                if key[1]['usuario'] == user:
                    ref_pass = key[0] #nombre
                    self.l_status.setText('')
                    self.validate_password(ref_pass)
                    break
                else:
                    self.l_status.setText("El usuario "+ user +" no fue encontrado")
                    break

    def validate_password(self,user):
        password  = self.l_password.text()

        refp = db.reference("/usuarios/"+user)
        res = refp.get()

        for key in res.items():
            if key[0] == 'password':
                if key[1] == password:
                    self.other()
                    self.l_status.setText("login")
                    pass
                else:
                    self.l_password.setText('')
                    self.l_status.setText("Invalidate Password")



    def other(self):
        self.close()
        self.inicio = Inicio()
        self.inicio.user.setText(self.l_usuario.text())
        self.inicio.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()
            event.accept()
    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(event.globalPos()-self.dragPosition)
            event.accept()

app = QApplication([])
p = Dato()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

**Inicio.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, QtNetwork, QtCore, QtGui, Qt, QtWidgets
import webbrowser
from Firebase_load import *
from Registro import Registro #modulo con problema
from Busqueda import Secundaria
from Inventario import mostrar
from Traspasos import Traspasos # modulo con problema

class Inicio(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Interfaces/Inicio.ui",self)


        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground,True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground,False)

        self.l_busqueda.setFocus()
        self.l_busqueda.installEventFilter(self)
        self.b_busqueda.clicked.connect(self.busqueda)
        self.add.clicked.connect(self.add_data)
        self.remove.clicked.connect(lambda:self.tabla.removeRow(self.tabla.currentRow()))
        self.Vender.clicked.connect(self.Vender_pro)
        self.Actualizar.clicked.connect(lambda:mostrar(self.tabla2))

        self.closed.clicked.connect(lambda:self.close())
        self.minim.clicked.connect(lambda:self.showMinimized())
        self.Maxim.clicked.connect(self.tamano_Principal)
        self.Limpiar.clicked.connect(self.clear_all)
        self.Registro.clicked.connect(lambda:Imagen_clas().show())
        self.Consulta.clicked.connect(lambda:Secundaria().show())
        self.Ventas.clicked.connect(lambda:self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0))
        self.Inventario.clicked.connect(lambda:self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1))
        self.Traspasos.clicked.connect(lambda:Traspasos().show())


        self.ag.clicked.connect(lambda:webbrowser.open('https://www.agelectronica.com/vs/'))
        self.cva.clicked.connect(lambda:webbrowser.open('https://www.grupocva.com/page/'))
        self.mitzu.clicked.connect(lambda:webbrowser.open('https://www.mitzu.com/'))
        self.steren.clicked.connect(lambda:webbrowser.open('https://www.steren.com.mx/'))

        self.b_steren.clicked.connect(lambda:webbrowser.open('https://www.steren.com.mx/catalogsearch/result/?q='+self.l_steren.text()))

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.mostrar_hora)
        self.timer.start()

    def clear_all(self):
        lista = [self.l_busqueda,self.l_producto,self.l_precio,self.l_marca,self.x1,self.x2,self.x3,self.l_imagen]
        for item in lista:
            item.clear()
        self.tabla.setRowCount(0)

    def eventFilter(self,obj,event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
                self.busqueda()
                return True
        return QtWidgets.QMainWindow.eventFilter(self,obj,event)

    def tamano_Principal(self):
        if self.isMaximized():
            self.showNormal()
        else:
            self.showMaximized()

    def mostrar_hora(self):
        t_now = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss")
        if t_now == '15:00:00':
            QMessageBox.information(None,"Recordatorio","Realizar corte de caja  "+t_now,QMessageBox.Ok)
        elif t_now == '17:00:00':
            QMessageBox.information(None,"Recordatorio","Realizar corte de caja  "+t_now,QMessageBox.Ok)
        elif t_now == '20:59:00':
            QMessageBox.information(None,"Recordatorio","Realizar corte de caja  "+t_now,QMessageBox.Ok)

        self.hora.setText(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss  AP"))

    def busqueda(self):
        codigo = self.l_busqueda.text()
        if len(codigo) > 4:
            self.busqueda_bar(codigo)

        else:
            ref  = db.reference('/Productos_Bar')
            r1 = ref.get()
            for key in r1.items():
                respuesta = key[1]['id']
                if respuesta == codigo:
                    nueva_ref = key[0]
                    self.busqueda_bar(nueva_ref)
                    self.l_busqueda.setText(codigo)
                    break
                else:
                    self.l_busqueda.setText('ID no encontrado')

    def busqueda_bar(self,code):
        ref_bus = db.reference('/Productos_Bar/'+str(code))
        refb = ref_bus.get()
        try:
            for key in refb.items():
                if key[0] == 'producto':
                    self.l_producto.setText(key[1])
                elif key[0] == 'precio':
                    self.l_precio.setText('$ '+str(key[1]))
                elif key[0] == 'marca':
                    self.l_marca.setText(key[1])
                elif key[0] == 'exe1':
                    self.x1.setText(str(key[1]))
                elif key[0] == 'exe2':
                    self.x2.setText(str(key[1]))
                elif key[0] == 'exe3':
                    self.x3.setText(str(key[1]))
                elif key[0] == 'url':
                    url = key[1]
                    manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager(self)
                    manager.finished.connect(self.onFinished)
                    manager.get(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl(url)))
                elif key[0] == 'id':
                    global _id
                    _id = key[1]
        except:
            self.l_busqueda.setText('Bar_code no definido')
        self.add_data()
        self.l_busqueda.setText('')

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtNetwork.QNetworkReply)
    def onFinished(self,reply):
        image = QtGui.QImage.fromData(reply.readAll())
        if not image.isNull():
            pixi = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image).scaled(150,150)
            self.l_imagen.setPixmap(pixi)
            self.l_imagen.resize(150,150)

    def add_data(self):
        try:
            self.tabla.insertRow(self.tabla.rowCount())
            item = QTableWidgetItem(_id)
            item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            item2 = QTableWidgetItem(self.l_producto.text())
            item2.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            item3 = QTableWidgetItem(self.l_marca.text())
            item3.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            item4 = QTableWidgetItem(self.l_precio.text())
            item4.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.tabla.setItem(self.tabla.rowCount()-1,0,item)
            self.tabla.setItem(self.tabla.rowCount()-1,1,item2)
            self.tabla.setItem(self.tabla.rowCount()-1,2,item3)
            self.tabla.setItem(self.tabla.rowCount()-1,3,item4)


        except:
            self.l_busqueda.setText("Error undefinited")

    def Vender_pro(self):

        precio = self.l_precio.text()
        prec = precio.lstrip('$ ')
        global sucursal
        sucursal = self.combo.currentText()
        acount =0
        result = 0
        venta = []
        global lista1
        lista1 = []
        global lista2
        lista2 = []
        global lista3
        lista3 = []

        if acount == 0:
            s = self.tabla.rowCount()
            for i in range(0,s):
                v = self.tabla.item(i,3).text()
                v1 = float(v.lstrip('$ '))
                venta.append(v1)
                lista1.append(self.tabla.item(i,0).text())
                lista2.append(self.tabla.item(i,1).text())
                lista3.append(prec)
            for vs in venta:
                result = result+vs
            acount = s 
        elif acount !=0:
            venta.clear()
            s = self.tabla.rowCount() - acount
            for i in range(0,s):
                v = self.tabla.item(i,3).text()
                v1 = float(v.lstrip('$ '))
                venta.append(v1)
                lista1.append(self.tabla.item(i,0).text())
                lista2.append(self.tabla.item(i,1).text())
            for vs in venta:
                result = result+vs 
            acount = 0

        ticket = Ticket()
        ticket.total(result)
        ticket.exec_()

    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()
            event.accept()
    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(event.globalPos()-self.dragPosition)
            event.accept()

class Ticket(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Interfaces/Venta.ui",self)
        self.b_Venta.clicked.connect(self.productos)
        self.b_Cancelar.clicked.connect(lambda:self.close())

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground,True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground,False)


    def total(self,total1):
        global n
        n = total1
        tr = round(n, 2)
        self.Total.setText('$ {}'.format(str(tr)))
        self.Cantidad.setFocus()
        self.Cantidad.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self,obj,event):
        if obj is self.Cantidad and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
                self.Calculo()
                return True
        return QDialog.eventFilter(self,obj,event)

    def Calculo(self):
        pago = float(self.Cantidad.text())
        operacion = pago-n
        opf = round(operacion, 2)
        op = str(opf)
        self.Cambio.setText('$ {}'.format(op))

    def productos(self):
        for i in lista1:
            self.producto_especifico_id(i,sucursal)

    def producto_especifico_id(self,identi,suc):
        try:
            if len(identi) > 4:
                self.producto_especifico_bar(identi,suc)
            else:
                ref = db.reference('/Productos_Bar')
                r1 = ref.get()
                for key in r1.items():
                    res = key[1]['id']
                    if res == identi:
                        new_ref = key[0]
                        self.producto_especifico_bar(new_ref,sucursal)
                        break
                    else:
                        pass
        except:
            pass

    def producto_especifico_bar(self,bar,sucursal):
        new_total = 0
        ref = db.reference('/Productos_Bar/'+str(bar))
        r0 = ref.get()
        total = 0 
        try:
            for key in r0.items():
                if sucursal == 'exe1':
                    if key[0] == 'exe1':
                        val = key[1]
                        total = val
                        if total == 0:
                            self.Cambio.setText('Producto sin inventario')
                            break 
                        else:
                            new_val = total -1
                            ref.update({
                                'exe1':new_val
                            })

                elif sucursal == 'exe2':
                    if key[0] == 'exe2':
                        val = key[1]
                        total = val
                        if total == 0:
                            self.Cambio.setText('Producto sin inventario')
                            break
                        else:
                            new_val = total -1
                            ref.update({
                                'exe2':new_val
                            })
                elif sucursal == 'exe3':
                    if key[0] == 'exe3':
                        val = key[1]
                        total = val
                        if total == 0:
                            self.Cambio.setText('Producto sin inventario')
                            break
                        else:
                            new_val = total -1
                            ref.update({
                                'exe3':new_val
                            })

        except:
            pass
        self.close()



#app = QApplication([])
#i = Inicio()
#i.show()
#app.exec_()
```

Espero puedan decirme que esta pasando.

**Actualización**

Después de hacer pruebas descubrí que lo que genera el ciclo es la importacion del modulo firebase dentro de mi modulo traspasos

**Traspasos**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog,QApplication,QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import uic, QtSql, QtGui, QtCore
#from Firebase_load import *
from Sqlite import cursor,conexion
import time
#from time import strftime
from firebase import firebase #modulo que genera el error

class Traspasos_class(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('Traspasos.ui',self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground,True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground,False)
        self.closed.clicked.connect(lambda:self.close())


#app = QApplication([])
#t = Traspasos_class()
#t.show()
#app.exec_()
```

la linea `from firebase import firebase` es la que ocasiona el error sin embargo no se por que .

Comment: No entiendo por qué lanzas un timer en el init en lugar de crear un nuevo Qthread, aunque puede que no sea eso. Para forzar la muerte del proceso puedes sobre-escribir el evento `closeEvent` y meter dentro `app.closeAllWindows()`

Comment: @Saelyth, el timer es para mostrar la hora, como un reloj, he estado revisando un poco y en el modulo Login, resulta que al importar el modulo inicio se presenta este error

Comment: app.closeAllwindows(), lanza un error 'python dejo de funcionar'